# Blocking tor from my website

Tags: windows-server-2008, asp.net, tor

I have a website written in ASP.NET MVC (and that means, it runs on windows server), that i want to protect from tor users. I thought about setting up some rules on windows firewall to block tor incoming connections, or something like that. Does anyone have any advices maybe? I would be very grateful.

Comment: ... "Protect" ?

Comment: Yes. Protect. When someone from darknet hacks your website, there is no way you will track them. Thats why i need to disable it.

Comment: You're probably better off hardening your application rather than trying to block all avenues of attack. Tracking down a hacker very rarely does any good anyway, since they're usually behind some other form of anonymizer anyway. Or, even if you did find them they're often in countries that won't help you out.

Comment: Don't do this without a very good reason. "I'm afraid of being hacked" isn't a good reason. There are a large number of [legitimate uses for Tor](https://www.torproject.org/about/torusers.html.en), and besides, you can't easily track down somebody who isn't using it when they break into your site, if they have half a clue. You lose visitors, and gain nothing, by blocking Tor.

Comment: Others saying this is a bad idea are right. However, often the person doing the implementing is not the person who made that decision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get a list of TOR exit nodes from https://check.torproject.org/cgi-bin/TorBulkExitList.py?ip=your.ip.add.ress where `your.ip.add.ress` is the IP address address of your server.

```
# This is a list of all Tor exit nodes that can contact your.ip.addr.ess on Port 80 #
# You can update this list by visiting https://check.torproject.org/cgi-bin/TorBulkExitList.py?ip=my.ip.addr.ess #
# This file was generated on Tue Dec  4 16:45:26 2012 UTC #
103.4.16.118
105.237.3.134  
.
.
.
98.250.89.34
99.194.201.167
```

You should be able to convert that into something that you can use to block TOR.

Comment: Neato. How frequently does that change?

Comment: @ceejayoz It can change very frequently, as exit nodes enter and leave the network.

Comment: Is there any way to translate this list of IPs into actual firewall rules easily?  I'd rather NOT have to go through this by hand and add firewall rules for each and every IP.

Comment: @ThomasW.: It would be fairly easy to do that.